# Downsides to using match + RouterContext on the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, isomorphic-javascript

Are there any downsides of using `match` and `RouterContext` instead of `Router` on the client? I've looked into [Router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/Router.js) and [match](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/modules/match.js) and don't see much of a difference.

Comment: Wasn't actually aware you could do that, `match` doesn't init browser based routing (e.g. `history={browserHistory}`) - did you try it?

Comment: @DominicTobias, yep we can; here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/Dattaya/d4d09eb3449c3f0e146e) and an [experimental branch](https://github.com/Dattaya/isomorphic-redux-plus/tree/universal-router-context-decorators). It would be nice to have one universal function for both, server&client. I just need to figure out downsides of this approach.